# Completion handler not called - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, methods, completionhandler

I have a simple iOS application with a IBAction. However the completion handler code is NOT running and I can't figure out why it's not running. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)didTapSignIn:(id)sender {

void (^handler)(id, id, id) = ^(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController, GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"TEST 2");

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        NSLog(@"AC: %@ \nRT: %@", auth.accessToken, auth.refreshToken);

        NSLog(@"AC TOKEN: %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.accessToken);
        NSLog(@"RF TOKEN: %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.refreshToken);
        NSLog(@"KEYCHAIN: %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].keychainName);

    }];

    NSLog(@"AC: %@ \nRT: %@", auth.accessToken, auth.refreshToken);

    NSLog(@"AC TOKEN: %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.accessToken);
    NSLog(@"RF TOKEN: %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.refreshToken);
    NSLog(@"KEYCHAIN: %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].keychainName);

    /*
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return;
    }

    else {
        BOOL signedIn = [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication];

        if (!signedIn) {
            NSLog(@"Sign In failed");
        }
    }*/
};

GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *controller = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" clientID:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID clientSecret:nil keychainItemName:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].keychainName completionHandler:handler];

NSLog(@"TEST 1");

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

NSLog(@"TEST 3");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It should run but it doesn't.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: What is done with the completionHandler in your GTMOauth2ViewControllerTouch? If you want the completionHandler after presenting your controller you should call [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:handler];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, one of the ways to to it is to pass `handler` to `[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:handler];`

But that would only be called when the view controller is dismissed.

It would be helpful if you could show more specifically `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch`:

I.e., this:

```
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch controllerWithScope:@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" clientID:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID clientSecret:nil keychainItemName:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].keychainName completionHandler:handler];
```

But given that you're calling `dismissViewController` in the callback, let assume that you want the completion handler called only when the process is finish and then dismiss the controller:

My guess is that you forgot to do the following when the process is done:

```
//process.... 
.......
//Done, call the handler
handler(id, id, id);
```

in your method above.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean but thanks anyway.